# My Binary search program simply shuts down

Tags: c++

my Binary search can only deliver the values for the first 4 entries in the array. For every greater value, the program gets stuck and shuts itself down, unless my value is in the upper half of the array, then it simply jumps to return -1... I really can't find my mistake here

```
int BinarySearch(int data[], int numElements, int searchKey)
{

    int mid;
    int numMin = 0;

    while (numMin <= numElements)
    {               
        mid = numMin + floorf ((numElements - 1)  / 2); // middle of the array initializing

        //Searched Value is right at the middle
        if (data[mid] == searchKey)
        {
            return mid;     

        }

        // If Searched value is greater, ignore left half
        else if (data[mid] < searchKey)
        {
            numMin = mid + 1; // new lowest value is middle of array +1

        }
        // If Searched value is smaller, ignore right half
        else
        {   
            numElements = mid - 1; // new highest value is middle of the array -1
        }

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and stepping line by line through your code inspecting variable values? You should do so

Comment: Ask yourself these questions: if you change `numMin`, is `numElements` still valid? And if you change `numElements`, is `numMin` still valid?

Comment: `numElements = mid - 1` is only valid when min is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong interpretation of `numElements`, you use it as number of elements at first but it should be the `endIndex`, while `numMin` should be `startIndex`.

first line of the while loop is wrong:

```
mid = numMin + floorf ((numElements - 1)  / 2);
```

It should be:

```
mid = (numMin + numElements) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mid = numMin + floorf ((numElements - 1)  / 2);
```

This will not calculate the `mid` correct version is

```
mid = numMin + floorf ((numElements - numMin)  / 2);
```

because when you add  `numMin` to `mid` you only need to add (`(numElements - numMin)  / 2`) to get the middle.

Or you can simply do as below.

```
mid = (numMin + numElements) / 2;
```